# Can I click anywhere on the header using Angular UI accordion?

Tags: angular-ui

I am using the Angular UI accordion and it works great. The only problem is you have to click the text and this seems like a really bad experience. Does anyone know a way to click anywhere in the header and have it toggle?

**Update**

I am still working on it, so far it looks like you would need to edit the [template HTML directly](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/accordion/accordion-group.html).

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" accordion-transclude="heading">
```

I tried to avoid this by creating an ng-click on the directive, however, this does not work.

```
<accordion-group heading="Company" data-ng-click="toggleOpen()">
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is enclose the contents of the  tag within a div.

```
 <accordion>
    <accordion-group is-open="status.open">
      <accordion-heading>
      <div>
        Accordion Title
        <i class="pull-right glyphicon"
          ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open,
          'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}">
        </i>
      </div>
      </accordion-heading>
      Accordion Contents
    </accordion-group>
 <accordion>
```

Comment: Thanks! However, this still not makes it clickable _anywhere_, but only around the same height as the header text. Is there a way to have the div fill out all of the header box, while keeping the text the same?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using bootstrap collapsible instead of accordion. I find the accordion controller to be far top buggy.